# Getting IMG to work With PHP

Tags: php, html, database, image

Code -

```
echo "<li>";
echo "<img src='$image'/>";
echo "</li>";
```

$image contains the location of the image on the server. the above code is not working...no image is displayed.

thanks.

GOT IT WORKING GUYS..SORRY...THERE WAS AN ISSUE WITH $IMAGE...NYWAYS THANKS, AND GREAT COMMUNITY...PROUD TO BE A PART OF THE GROWING.

Comment: Looks correct assuming $image contains the URL of the image hosted on the server, not the file path.

Comment: What HTML gets rendered?

Comment: Can you please give a clue about the value you are passing in $image???And make sure that the image path is correct.